# If $a+b\equiv 0 \mod 2$ then $a,b$ are both odd or even by using contrapositive.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The statement:

If $(x+y)\equiv 0 \mod 2$ $\Rightarrow$ ($x$ is even and $y$ is even ) or ($x$ is odd and $y$ is odd)

Contrapositive:

($x$ is odd or $y$ is odd ) and ($x$ is even or $y$ is even)$\Rightarrow$ $(x+y)\equiv 0 \mod 2$

My work:

($x$ is odd or $y$ is odd ) and ($x$ is even or $y$ is even) means $x,y$ are $(odd,even)$ or $(even,odd)$ so $x=2n+1,y=2k$  or $x=2n,y=2k+1$

so $x+y=2(n+k)+1$ or $x+y=2(n+k)+1$ and both are not divisible by 2.

Could you suggest a more elegant way to prove it?

Comment: You can make the argument a touch more elegant by noting the symmetery of the variables $x$ and $y$, and say, "Without loss of generality, assume $x$ is odd and $y$ is even." That will save you a case. Otherwise, I think you're not going to get much more elegant.

Comment: The contrapositive should be: If it is not the case that ($x$ is even and $y$ is even) or ($x$ is odd and $y$ is odd), then $(x+y)\not\equiv 0 \bmod 2$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a$,$b$ have different parity. Then without loss of generality $a \equiv 1 \pmod2$, $b \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ and $a+b \not\equiv 0 \pmod2$.